# How to convert date and time in excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have downloaded a log file in .csv format. When I opened the file using MS excel, the format and the time displayed are different from the actual system log. Example as below:

**System Log**

Date [Column Header]

1/21/2022, 8:09:11 PM

**Excel**

Date UTC [Column Header]

2022-01-21T12:09:11Z

How to get the Microsoft Excel to display the same format or at least the correct time as the system log?

Comment: What you write doesn't usually happen when you **open** a csv file using Excel. Please provide a copy/paste (or link to a text file) of the actual csv (as seen in a **text editor**).  And when you write *open* are you just using the Open method, or are you importing the file using one of the import wizards?  Do you do anything after you **open** the file before you see those results?

Answer (score 0):

So Excel does a timezone conversion to UTC, it assumes, that the timezone for the data is UTC+8.

If you want Excel to display the date in another format, just change the format in the cell format dialog.[image: cell format dialog]